# Unexpected keyword 'this'

Tags: reactjs

i have created a component if i write  `{this.state.tags.length === 0 ? "hello" : <ul>{this.gettag()}</ul> }` i am getting no error if I write like this  `{this.state.tags.length === 0 ? "hello" : {this.gettag()} }`  with out ul tag I am getting error here is my  code

```
class Count extends Component {
   state={
       tags:['kukab', 'saqib' , '40'],
   };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.tags.length === 0 ? "hello" : <ul>{this.gettag()}</ul> }
                
            </div>
            
        );
    }
    gettag(){
    return(
        <div>
           
        <ul>{this.state.tags.map(tag => <li key={tag}>{tag}</li> )}</ul>

        </div>
    )

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call this function without `<ul>` tag, Use `{this.state.tags.length === 0 ? "hello" : this.gettag()}`.  Just remove two curly braces surrounding `this.gettag()`. But if you want to use it inside `<ul>` tag, Use `{this.state.tags.length === 0 ? "hello" : <ul>{this.gettag()}</ul>}`

Comment: @kokab In JSX (the kind of HTML+JS markup used in React), you use curly braces to insert JS code inside HTML code. In your case, `this.gettag()` is already inside curly braces (those of the whole expression), so no need for another set of braces. Probably the JS interpreter just got confused and thought you were declaring an object using these extra braces, hence the error, but that's just a wild guess.